# substring between two delimiters in java

Tags: java, android, html, extract

I have a string as :

```
<head>

    <script type="text/javascript">window._timings = {"domLoading": Date.now()}</script>

        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<script type="text/javascript">window._sharedData = {"country_code": "IR", "language_code": "en", "gatekeepers": {"cc": true, "sms": true, "ra": true}, "show_app_install": false, "static_root": "//instagramstatic-a.akamaihd.net/h1", "platform": "web"};</script>
<script src="//instagramstatic-a.akamaihd.net/h1/bundles/en_US_ProfilePage.js/88ce62d41e70.js" type="text/javascript" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

I just need to extract :

```
{"country_code": "IR", "language_code": "en", "gatekeepers": {"cc": true, "sms": true, "ra": true}, "show_app_install": false, "static_root": "//instagramstatic-a.akamaihd.net/h1", "platform": "web"}
```

Need help on this.

Comment: Use JSoup to parse html elements also try JSON parser

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In terms of simple string parsing you could use some function like this:

```
public static String between(String start, String end, String input) {
    int startIndex = input.indexOf(start);
    int endIndex = input.lastIndexOf(end);
    if(startIndex == -1 || endIndex == -1) return input;
    else return input.substring(startIndex + start.length(), endIndex + end.length()).trim();
}
```

In that case usage will be the following:

```
String input = "<head>\n" +
        "\n" +
        "    <script type=\"text/javascript\">window._timings = {\"domLoading\": Date.now()}</script>\n" +
        "\n" +
        "        <meta charset=\"utf-8\">\n" +
        "        <meta http-equiv=\"X-UA-Compatible\" content=\"IE=edge\">\n" +
        "<script type=\"text/javascript\">window._sharedData = {\"country_code\": \"IR\", \"language_code\": \"en\", \"gatekeepers\": {\"cc\": true, \"sms\": true, \"ra\": true}, \"show_app_install\": false, \"static_root\": \"//instagramstatic-a.akamaihd.net/h1\", \"platform\": \"web\"};</script>\n" +
        "<script src=\"//instagramstatic-a.akamaihd.net/h1/bundles/en_US_ProfilePage.js/88ce62d41e70.js\" type=\"text/javascript\" crossorigin=\"anonymous\"></script>";
System.out.println(between("window._sharedData =", "}", input));
```

Result is as expected:

```
{"country_code": "IR", "language_code": "en", "gatekeepers": {"cc": true, "sms": true, "ra": true}, "show_app_install": false, "static_root": "//instagramstatic-a.akamaihd.net/h1", "platform": "web"}
```

Comment: Thanks but this string you string me different.In fact, my string is source a site ,and code  <script type=\"text/javascript\">window._sharedData = {\"... is between that

Comment: Do not quite get your concern. You specified expected result in question and I provided function to achieve that based on you input data. Either update question to be more specific or accept the answer :)